# Requirements for Keyword Argument Unpacking

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

What is required to support keyword argument unpacking for a custom class in Python? In both the Python 2.7 and Python 3.6 interpreters the following error message is given when trying to unpack an incompatible type:

```
>>> dict(**None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: type object argument after ** must be a mapping, not NoneType
```

Does *mapping* mean the object has to specifically subclass `collections.Mapping`? Or is *mapping* in this case one of those pseudo types such as *iterable* where you don't have to explicitly subclass `collections.Iterable` to support `iter()`? Does this behavior differ between Python 2 and 3?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> A Mapping is a generic container for associating key/value pairs.

It is not compulsory to inherit from `collections.Mapping` in order to use dictionary unpacking. Besides, `collections.Mapping` is an abstract class, so you'll still have to override some methods in order to be able to use dict unpacking with any of its subclasses.

For an instance of a class to be *dict unpackable*, it is enough for the class to implement a `keys` method and a corresponding `__getitem__` method to return a value given a key:

```
class D(object):
  def __getitem__(self, key):
      return 2

  def keys(self):
      return ['1','2','3']

print(dict(**D()))
# {'1': 2, '2': 2, '3': 2}
```

Comment: That's interesting.  I'm surprised that it's not sufficent to implement `__iter__`, which is require by `Mapping`, while `keys` isn't

Comment: `__iter__` is more general for objects that implement the iterator protocol and is not restricted to mapping. A map must be able to return a value, given a a key, and `__getitem__` does that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Python [glossary entry](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-mapping) for `mapping`:

> A container object that supports arbitrary key lookups and implements the methods specified in the Mapping or MutableMapping abstract base classes. Examples include dict, collections.defaultdict, collections.OrderedDict and collections.Counter.